# Show "Accessible" button on tab

Tags: html, css, user-controls

I am trying to show a button to access Accessibility options on the top of the page - normally hidden - when the user tabs to them.

HTML:

```
<a href="" class="access" accesskey="1" tabindex="1">Accessbility Options</a>
```

Style:

```
.access {display:none; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; padding:10px; font-size:25px; background:#eaeaea;}
.access:focus {display:block;}
```

However when you use the tab button once the page has first loaded, nothing shows. I have tried using :hover rather than focus etc; but I am struggling to find similar answers which handle it without any jQuery / over complicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
display:none;
```

you could use

```
.access {opacity:0; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; padding:10px; font-size:25px; background:#eaeaea;}
.access:focus {opacity:1;}
```

Something with display:none will not be given an actual tabindex.

Answer (score 1):

An Element with

```
display: none;
```

is not able to get focus!
You have to use another way to get the element invisible.
For example positioning it outside of the page, or opacity (note that it is clickable even if it is not visible).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: hidden` or look [into this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937599/tab-into-an-input-within-a-hidden-element) for a JavaScript solution